# What is the Jboss4 xml configuration equivalent of ActivationConfigProperty?

Tags: jboss, jboss-4.0.x

I have an MDB deployed nicely within JBoss-4.0.4 with this annotation.  It works very well.

```
@MessageDriven(
   activationConfig = {
      @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", 
           propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
      @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", 
           propertyValue = "queue/mycompany/thing/thingy"),
      @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "MaxPoolSize", 
           propertyValue = "4")        
   }
)
```

Now I need to externalise that configuration so I can change MaxPoolSize without having to recompile and redeploy the code. [According to the docs](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/admindevel326/html/ch5.chapter.html) it looks this should appear in the standardjboss.xml as a new `<proxy-factory-config>` but what value should I use for `<JMSProviderAdapterJNDI>`, `<ServerSessionPoolFactoryJNDI>` etc?  Is this change (adding a new `<proxy-factory-config>` element) the only thing I need?

```
<proxy-factory-config>
<JMSProviderAdapterJNDI>WHATGOESHERE?</JMSProviderAdapterJNDI>
<ServerSessionPoolFactoryJNDI>WHATGOESHERE?</ServerSessionPoolFactoryJNDI>
<MaximumSize>3</MaximumSize>
<MaxMessages>1</MaxMessages>
<MDBConfig>
    <ReconnectIntervalSec>10</ReconnectIntervalSec>
    <DLQConfig>
        <DestinationQueue>queue/mycompany/thing/thingy</DestinationQueue>
        <MaxTimesRedelivered>10</MaxTimesRedelivered>
        <TimeToLive>0</TimeToLive>
    </DLQConfig>
</MDBConfig>
</proxy-factory-config>
```

Comment: http://www.jboss.ru/docs/JBoss-2001-06-28/ch07s07.html might have something. It recommends `<JMSProviderAdapterJNDI>DefaultJMSProvider</JMSProviderAdapterJNDI>` and `<ServerSessionPoolFactoryJNDI>StdJMSPool</ServerSessionPoolFactoryJNDI>`